# Delta function in the sense of distributions

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I have a problem understanding the meaning of the delta-function on the sense of distributions. E.g. I have the following equation:

$$\left(\frac{d}{dt} \theta(t) \right) f(t) = \delta(t) f(t)$$

What does this mean for the function $f(t)$? I cannot really understand what the delta function does here in the sense of a distribution.

Comment: A "distribution" is a functional  that assigns a number to every function.  The "delta function" assigns the number f(0) to the function f.  $\delta(t)f(t)= f(0)$

Comment: Thanks! Actually I need to show that $\delta(t) f(t) = \delta(t)$. I know, that f(0) = 1, so I think that this is correct then? Or does the $\delta(t)$ disappear then after acting on f(t)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume $f$ is $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$.

$\delta f$ is a nonsense, however $f\delta$ has a meaning. One is only allowed to multiply a distribution by a smooth function ($\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})\times\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$), the product of a smooth function by a distribution is not defined.

> **Definition.** Let $T\in\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$ and $f\in\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$, one define $fT$ by: $$\forall\varphi\in\mathcal{C}^{\infty}_0(\mathbb{R}),\langle fT,\varphi\rangle=\langle T,f\varphi\rangle.$$

*Remark.* $f\varphi\in\mathcal{C}^{\infty}_0(\mathbb{R})$, since $\textrm{supp}(f\varphi)\subseteq\textrm{supp}(\varphi)$.

One has the:

> **Proposition.** Let $T\in\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$ and $f\in\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$, $fT\in\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$.

**Proof.** Since $T$ is a distribution, $fT$ is cleary linear map from $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}_0(\mathbb{R})$ to $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}_0(\mathbb{R})$. Let $K$ be a compact of $\mathbb{R}$, since, $T$ is a distribution there exists $C\in\mathbb{R}_+^*$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that: $$\forall\varphi\in\mathcal{C}_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}),\textrm{supp}(\varphi)\subseteq K,|\langle T,\varphi\rangle|\leqslant C\sum_{i=1}^n\sup_{K}\left|\varphi^{(i)}\right|
$$ Let $\varphi\in\mathcal{C}^{\infty}_0(\mathbb{R})$, $\textrm{supp}(f\varphi)\subset K$ and one has: $$\begin{align}|\langle fT,\varphi\rangle|&=|\langle T,f\varphi\rangle|\\&\leqslant C\sum_{i=1}^k\sup_{K}\left|(f\varphi)^{(i)}\right|\\&\leqslant C\sum_{i=1}^k\sup_{K}\left|\sum_{j=0}^i{i\choose j}f^{(j)}\varphi^{(i-j)}\right|\\&\leqslant C\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=0}^i{i\choose j}\sup_{K}\left|f^{(i)}\right|\sup_{K}\left|\varphi^{(j-i)}\right|\\&\leqslant\widetilde{C}\sum_{i=1}^k\sup_{K}\left|\varphi^{(i)}\right|\end{align}.$$
Hence, $fT$ is a distribution. $\Box$

*Remark.* $\widetilde{C}$ can for example be : $$C\max_{i\in\{1,\ldots,k\}}\left(\max_{j\in\{1,\ldots,i\}}{i\choose j}\sup_{K}\left|f^{(i)}\right|\right).$$

---

In your case, one has: $$\forall\varphi\in\mathcal{C}_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}),\langle f\delta,\varphi\rangle=(f\varphi)(0)=f(0)\langle\delta,\varphi\rangle.$$
Therefore, one gets: $$f\delta=f(0)\delta.$$

Comment: This is the best answer I could ever think of. Thank you so much! And you are right, it was of course $f \delta$ and not $\delta f$.